# Remove page layout from sharepoint pages library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint Pages library we have pages, Artical Page and Welcome Page content type. And with this content type their are default OOB page layouts like basic page, image on left, body only etc. Now I have created my own content type and Page Layout. I want to remove all default page layout that SharePoint provides from pages library.

How can i do that?

Comment: Why have you changed you question after multiple answers have been added, and one has been accepted as an answer? If you have a new question, post it as a new question

Answer (score 4):

- In the pages library, chose Library Settings in the ribbon.
- Select Advanced settings
- In *Allow management of content types?* select Yes

[image]

- Back on the settings page, chose *Change new button order and default content type* and select which one should be visible.

[image]

- Or select a content type, and chose *Delete this content type*. This will remove the content type from the library, but not on the sites content type.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the default page layouts , go to **Site settings**-> **Page layouts and site templates**
Under page layouts category, select **Pages in this site can only use the following layouts** and add the layout to be used.[image]

Comment: I want to delete all this default page layout programmatically

Comment: do you want to delete it from the site iteself?

Comment: no.. for only page library

Comment: I think page layouts will not available in page library only when removed from the site